# How to use Auth::check() for Users who logged in via Hybridauth Package in Laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, hybridauth

I managed to work hybridauth package in Laravel 4.1 and I am able to get twitter info of a user.

I add a user row to the users table for the first time users. However, this row doesn't have email and password values which are used in Auth::attemp() function to authenticate non-social users.

My question is that, should I use Auth::attemp() function for social users? If not, how can I make valid Auth::check() functions in controller and blade files?

Comment: I would recommend after successful login with Hybridauth call Auth::attempt() with for example facebook id or other unique user identification which can be getted from Hybridauth and are saved in db

Comment: But attempt() function accepts password field. Is twitter id as a parameter valid?

Comment: yes, it is valid. Imagine, you have column `twitter_id` in `users` table and want login user with specific tw_id so you just call `Auth::attempt(['twitter_id' => Input::get('twitter_id')])`